# Missing text from boxes in block diagram (pst-sigsys/pstricks)

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to make a block diagram using pst-sigsys/pstricks. The text however isn't in the boxes but is stashed on the left. I absolutely run out of ideas what might be causing it to happen. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-sigsys}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering %
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](0,5)(8,9)

%--- Define blocks ---
\psfblock[framesize=2.5 1](2,7){R11}{Axon Count}
\psfblock[framesize=2.5 1](6,7){R12}{Axon Diameter}

%--- Connect blocks ---
\psset{style=Arrow}
\ncline{R11}{R12} \naput[npos=.5]{(+)}

\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I get the text properly boxed; it may be a problem in the viewer. Did you try producing a PDF?

Comment: Do not view the DVI output. Always look at the PS or PDF output (as already mentioned).

Comment: Thank you egreg. Indeed if I produce DVI and convert it to postscript everything looks okay, but if I do DVI -> PDF things are out of whack. I guess there is a reason this package is called pstricks ;-) Thank you once again!

Comment: @Jacek: run the example with `xelatex`, then the pdf will be fine.

Comment: I suggest somebody turns his comment into an answer. Btw. I can confirm it works with XeLaTeX too.

Comment: @Herbert: I think it should be you to give the answer

Answer (score 1):

*Comment to answer*

Thorsten Donig  (+1)

> Do not view the DVI output. Always look at the PS or PDF output (as
>   already mentioned).

Herbert

> run the example with xelatex, then the pdf will be fine.